# Как обновить ACF Image c помощь update_field?

Tags: php, wordpress, acf

Я использую Advanced Custom Fields плагин в Wordpress

```
$attachment_id = media_handle_upload( 'userpic_file', 0 ); // это работает.
update_field('userpic', $attachment_id, get_current_user_id() ); // это не работает
```

Кто-нибудь, объяснить, что я делаю не так и почему картинка не обновляется? Нигде не могу найти инфу касательно update_field и custom field "Image".
Может ему надо не id изображения передавать, а массив?

Answer (score 0):

В общем все оказалось крайне просто.
Если обновляешь custom field юзера, то нужно писать id с префиксом user_
Правильный вариант:

```
update_field('userpic', $attachment_id, 'user_'.get_current_user_id() );
```